# How to convert a file to string directly using C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, string

I asked a question regarding how to display aspx and cs code on page,

One answer was to convert to string and display in textbox.

Is there a function in C# ASP.NET which allows to convert file contents directly to a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use System.IO.File.ReadAllText().